# How to get the userId of logged in user blazor server in CODE BEHIND or .CS file

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-identity

I have retrieved the userId in a Blazor component using the code below:
[CascadingParameter]
public Task AuthenticationStateTask { get; set; }

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    YoogieContext cxt = new YoogieContext();
    var authState = await AuthenticationStateTask;  
    var user = authState.User;
    var UserStringId = user.FindFirst(c => c.Type.Contains("nameidentifier"))?.Value;
}
```

How do I get the userId from a code behind (.cs) file? Using Blazor Server.

Comment: Is this your answer? stackoverflow.com/a/74219805/4444757

Comment: What exactly you are looking for? Do you want to access the auth state without using a Blazor component? If yes, then it depends on the architecture. If not and you want to do it for simple refactoring - then create a class that inherits from ComponentBase, put your OnInitializedAsync() code there and let your actual razor component inherit from that class.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, when doing that, I get a object null reference error. So that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Revised Answer

The cascaded `Task<AuthenticationStateTask>` is derived from the `AuthenticationStateProvider` so you might as well use it in code behind classes.  You have to use it in service classes, there's no cacaded value to access.

The advantage of dropping back to the underlying `AuthenticationStateProvider` is you get access to the identity change events, so can react when the identity changes.

Here's a simple service to demonstrate interacting with the AuthenticationStateProvider:

```cs
public class MyIdentityService : IDisposable
{
    private AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;

    public event EventHandler<IdentityChangedEventArgs>? IdentityChanged;

    public MyIdentityService(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
    {
        // The dependancy container will inject it's AuthenticationStateProvider instance here
        _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
        // register for the state changed event
        _authenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged += NotifyIdentityChanged;
    }

    // Method to get the current Identity
    public async ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> GetCurrentIdentity()
    {
        AuthenticationState state = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        return state.User;
    }

    // Fire and forget async event handler that waits on the Task completion before invoking the Event
    private async void NotifyIdentityChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> newAuthStateTask)
    {
        AuthenticationState state = await newAuthStateTask;
        this.IdentityChanged?.Invoke(null, new() { Identity = state.User});
    }

    // de-register for the state changed event
    public void Dispose()
        => _authenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged -= NotifyIdentityChanged;
}

// Custom Event Args class to pass the new identity
public class IdentityChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ClaimsPrincipal Identity { get; init; } = new ClaimsPrincipal();
}
```

registered in Program:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<MyIdentityService>();
```

My `Index.razor`

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div class="alert alert-info">
    Identity 1: @(this.Identity1.Identity?.Name ?? "No User Logged In")
    </div>
<div class="alert alert-success">
    Identity 2: @(this.Identity2.Identity?.Name ?? "No User Logged In")
</div>
```

And a code behind file that shows using the `AuthenticationStateProvider` directly and the  `MyIdentityService`.

```cs
public partial class Index : ComponentBase, IDisposable
{
    private ClaimsPrincipal Identity1 = new ClaimsPrincipal();
    private ClaimsPrincipal Identity2 = new ClaimsPrincipal();

    [Inject] private AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider { get; set; } = default!;
    [Inject] private MyIdentityService _myService { get; set; } = default!;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        AuthenticationState state = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        Identity1 = state.User;
        _authenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged += OnAuthenticationStateChanged;

        Identity2 = await _myService.GetCurrentIdentity();
        this._myService.IdentityChanged += OnIdentityChanged;
    }


    private async void OnAuthenticationStateChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> newAuthStateTask)
    {
        AuthenticationState state = await newAuthStateTask;
        Identity1 = state.User;
        // if you want to update the component when the identity changes
        await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    private async void OnIdentityChanged(object? sender, IdentityChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Identity2 = e.Identity;
        // if you want to update the component when the identity changes
        await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _authenticationStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged -= OnAuthenticationStateChanged;
        this._myService.IdentityChanged -= OnIdentityChanged;
    }
}
```

Here's my test page - I've used Windows authentication for simplicity.

[image]

Comment: [Polite] The OP displays some code that he uses to get the user id in a component (.razor). Now he's asking how to do the same thing in `CODE BEHIND or .CS file` He's actually asking how to create, say, a partial class file(.razor.cs) and embed the very same code in it. Can't you tell him that?

Comment: Guilty as charged - mis-understood the question!  Now I don't fully understand what the OP wants.  Surely refactoring a razor file and adding a code behind file is too obvious??  If so, it doesn't need an answer, just RTFM!

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis  Is your answer "RTFM" ?  As for your "Surely refactoring a razor file and adding a code behind file is too obvious??", I must apologize for not having your superior knowledge.

Comment: [Polite] No.  I've revised my answer based on your response higher up.  PS no judgement intended.  It was intended as a flippant remark to @enet that maybe he had also misunderstood your question!  Any questions on my answer, ask.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis  Thank you ever so much for your detailed answer! I would not have got this in a month of Sundays!! I have it up and running now. Just one question remains, I also need the UserId ? I was going to run a LINQ query on the email address to get the UserId, but instinct tells me this is not best practice.?

Comment: `Claims` is an `IEnumerable<Claim>`, so Linq is as good as any.  Use `string name = _identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(....) ?? "Not Logged In"`.  Also check the `Identity` property object of `ClaimsPrincipal`. It does the work for you (populates itself with most of the common information from the `Claims` collection) - check `_identity.Identity.Name`.

Comment: @JakeL - You should mark this as the answer if it is your accepted answer.